# Standard Navigation Menu on all sub ASP.Net Pages

Tags: c#, php, html, asp.net, web

Hello I wanted a navigation menu for my website, and wanted to create it so that it will be shown on every webpage where I implement it. and when I change something on the navigation that it gets updated for all the other websites where I put the navigation on.

I have heared from a Master Page but I dont think that it will update all sites when I do a change on it.

It would be silly to create a menu and then copy paste it on the other 50 subpages or so.

Regards

Comment: So, you have multiple website and you want to use one menu for all website?

Comment: For your scenario, I would like you to consider Custom controls. Create your custom control for menu and add this control to all your websites. However any changes in custom control, you need to update the dll for all websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Master Page is exactly what you are looking for. Just make sure that all of your other pages use that Master Page, and whenever you change it it will affect all the pages using it.

Comment: Can I add a Masterpage after I already created some Pages? Because I created some pages before i thought about a Menu and now i want to implement the menu

Comment: Yes you can, just add the newly created Master Page to the other pages like this:
<% @ Page Language="C#" **MasterPageFile="~/YourMasterPage.master"** Title="Some Title" %>